# Is there a business English word for cancellation after due date?

Tags: single-word-requests

A booking process has a cancellation option. People can cancel up to 2 days from the start date of a booking. If they cancel after the start date minus 2 days, we charge them for late cancellation. Is there an appropriate business word for this kind of late cancellation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard term for this in airline reservations is *Late Cancellation / No Show* policy.